# C++ program sometimes giving wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this program, which should give me the smallest original price of the item based on the input from the user.
There are some conditions, for example, if the quantity of the mask is more than 9 the price will be discounted by 10%, 15% if its more than 30 and 20% if it's more than 50. The result should give the answer Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
    int mprice; //price input
    int mquantity; //quantity input
    int n; //first input
    int fee = 2000; //const fee
    float finalprice;
    float maskCalc(int price, int quantity) {
        float holder = (float)(price - fee) / (float)(quantity);
            if (quantity > 0) {
                finalprice = holder;
            }
            //if between 10 and 30
            else if (quantity > 9) {
                finalprice = holder / 0.9;
            }
            //between 30 and 49
            else if (quantity > 30) {
                finalprice = holder / 0.85;
            }
            //more than 50
            else if (quantity > 49) {
                finalprice = holder / 0.8;
            }
            //less than ten
            else {
                finalprice = holder;
            }
        return finalprice;
    }
int main()
{   
    cin >> n;
    float arr[n];
    // Input oruulah loop
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> mprice >> mquantity;
        x = maskCalc(mprice, mquantity);
        arr[i] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[0] > arr[i]) {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%.2f", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I gave the input
3 
5000 3
7000 10
3000 1
the answer was 555.56 which is correct, but when I give something like
3
2500 1
7000 10
3000 1
it is giving me 0.00 while I was expecting this to give me 500.00. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: and what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the highest quantity first in your if-else switch, otherwise you always fall into the default (<10) case.

```
        //more than 50
        if (quantity >= 50) {
            finalprice = holder / 0.8;
        }
        //between 30 and 49
        else if (quantity >= 30) {
            finalprice = holder / 0.85;
        }
        //if between 10 and 30
        else if (quantity >= 10) {
            finalprice = holder / 0.9;
        }
        //less than ten
        else {
            finalprice = holder;
        }
```